# Moderncv and left Margin - How to shrink the column with the dates?

Tags: moderncv

I have tried to reduce the left margins with the package `geometry`:  `\usepackage[scale=0.90, top=0.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}` but cannot shrink the column where we have the dates in the experience section. I'm new with LaTeX and cannot find a proper solution?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 


\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{orange}   

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[scale=0.90, top=0.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry} %If you want to change the page margins, you simply need to change this line

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm} 

\name{David}{Doe}
%\title{Audit, Risk and Compliance\newline{}PMP®, ITIL, CRISC} 
\title{PMP®, ITIL, CRISC} 
%\address{}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+XXXXXXXX} 
\email{emil.com}  
\social[linkedin][WWWWW]{ZZZZ}
\photo[80pt][0pt]{David_linkedn}  

\renewcommand{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \newline{\small\strut #7 \par}}}

\renewcommand{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{mycvlist}
    \item[#2] #3
    \end{mycvlist}
    \addvspace{#1}}

\newlist{mycvlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[mycvlist]{labelwidth=\hintscolumnwidth,labelsep=\separatorcolumnwidth,leftmargin=!,align=right,font=\normalfont}

\usepackage{lipsum} %Just for dummy text

%\title{Resum\'e title}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{Professional Statement }

ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd


\begin{itemize}
    \item  \begin{center} item1 \end{center}
    \item  \begin{center} item2 \end{center}
    \item  \begin{center} item2 \end{center}
\end{itemize}
%I'm seeking new challenge and opportunity to leverage that experience in a Global Pharmaceutical Company.




\section{Experience}

\cventry{Since \linebreak March 2019}{
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD}{\href{http://www.DDD.com//}{DDDDDA}}{SSSSS}{}{LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL

Main achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%


  \item \textit {\textbf{GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGggg }}
\begin{itemize}%
  \item \textbf{Key Highlight}: GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGgggg
  \item \textbf{Purpose}: GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
  \item \textbf{Results}:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
    \item GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGgg
    \item GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGgggg
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
```

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Please reformat to display your code as such.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please make your example code a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduces the output you show. If Itry to make a small example out of your code fragment, I get a significantly different output. Please also remove code that is not related to your ussue.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the date column is set with the `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}` line in your example.

Since you're new to TeX and friends, a good general advice when you're using a new package you're not familiar with, is to go over [CTAN](https://ctan.org/), search for the [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv?lang=en), and browse its associated documentation.

Sadly in this case the package `moderncv` does not have a proper manual in CTAN, but if you go to [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv), there is [a PDF userguide.](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/raw/master/manual/moderncv_userguide.v2.pdf) that may be of use for further modifications.